# Why does LinearSolve return the transpose of the answer matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve an equation of the form $dv=F\cdot dV$ where $dv$ and $dV$ are matrices derived from the row vectors $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ and $dX$, $dY$, $dZ$ respectively. If it helps, $F$ is the deformation gradient operating on material vectors to get spatial.

**Problem setup:**

```
dX = {1, 0, 0};
dY = {1, 1, 0};
dZ = {1, 1, 1};
dx = {1, 0, 0};
dy = {0, 1, 1};
dz = {0, 0, 1};

dV = {dX, dY, dZ};
dv = {dx, dy, dz};

F = Table[Subscript[Ff, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
varList = Flatten[F]
```

**Solutions:**

I saw a video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZY987biWIg) where someone took the approach:

```
Solve[{F.dX == dX, F.dY == dy, F.dZ == dz}, varList]
```

I rewrote it as:

```
Solve[{Transpose[F].dV == dv}, varList]
```

But ultimately went with this approach:

```
LinearSolve[dV, dv] //Transpose
```

I knew to add the `//Transpose` after comparing the output with previous results so my question is whether there a logical reason why the result is transposed though I know that `LinearSolve` is meant to solve equations of the form $Ax=b$ for $x$ but in this case I am trying to solve for $A$, supplying $x$ and $b$ as arguments.

Please any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I might not be able to visually inspect results in more complicated cases.

Comment: Um, note that LinearSolve solves Ax==b. In your case, the equation is b==xA. Teake's solution solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gregory, I didn't quite catch that distinction :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to be a bit careful here; your last approach does not give the desired matrix `F`:

```
(LinearSolve[dV, dv] // Transpose).dV === dv
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Then what does give the correct output? We can use the fact that for generic matrices $A$ and $B$ we have $A.B = (B^T.A^T)^T$ and write

```
F = Transpose @ LinearSolve[Transpose @ dV, Transpose @ dv]
```

And indeed, we've now got the correct output:

```
F.dV === dv
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Note whenever `dV` is invertible, you may also simply do

```
F = dv.Inverse[dV]
```

to get the same result.

Comment: Thank you @Teake Nutma for your insightful answer. I will revise my work accordingly.